# Remove element after success click from DOM - Test Angular

Tags: angular, dom, element

how do I please test if deleting the link element works for me?
With link.remove () I try to remove the element from the DOM, but I don't know whether it works.

```
var downloadURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);

var link = document.createElement('a');

link.href = downloadURL;
link.download = fileName;
link.click();
link.remove();
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to append it `document.body.appendChild(link);` and then you can remove it in DOM `document.body.removeChild(a);`

```
var downloadURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);
var link = document.createElement('a');

// Add this line
document.body.appendChild(link);

link.href = downloadURL;
link.download = fileName;
link.click();

// Add this line
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question, how can I test it?

Comment: @SylviaMaťašová I have a demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blob-file-download-5m6erh?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts. You can see I use the above code to download a file and remove it out of DOM.

Comment: Thank you very much.